# Undefined Boost reference when compiling mongo-perf on CentOS 6.3

Tags: mongodb, boost, compiler-errors, centos

I'm attempting to compile [mongo-perf](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-perf) by adapting the instructions [here](http://blog.beyondfog.com/mongodb-how-to-benchmark-and-test-performance-using-mongo-perf/) for CentOS 6.3. I have already followed these instructions on Ubuntu successfully.

I successfully compiled MongoDB, but when running scons to compile mongo-perf, I get errors about undefined boost references.

```
[davidv@mongodb-test1 mongo-perf]$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C library mongoclient... (cached) yes
Checking for C library boost_thread-mt... (cached) yes
Checking for C library boost_filesystem-mt... (cached) yes
Checking for C library boost_program_options-mt... (cached) yes
Checking for C library boost_system-mt... (cached) yes
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o benchmark -pthread -g benchmark.o -Lmongo-cxx-driver -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_system-mt
/usr/local/lib64/libmongoclient.a(dbclient_rs.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/davidv/mongodb-src-r2.4.3/src/third_party/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/davidv/mongodb-src-r2.4.3/src/third_party/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/home/davidv/mongodb-src-r2.4.3/src/third_party/boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
...
```

As you can see, I do have boost_system-mt installed, and it's referenced at the end of the g++ command.

Versions:

- g++ 4.4.7
- ld 2.20.51.0.2-5.34.el6
- scons v2.0.1.r5134
- boost-system 1.41.0-17.el6_4

I'm generally unfamiliar with SCons and the Boost libraries. What can I do to fix this compilation problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when I [RTFM](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-perf#benchmarks-1) a little closer, turns out the correct way to compile mongo-perf is actually the following:

```
# compile the C++ driver (in mongo-perf)
cd mongo-cxx-driver && scons 
# compile the benchmark script
cd .. && scons benchmark
```

Not sure why the linked instructions worked OK on Ubuntu, but there you have it.